# Tricky associative arrays in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, associative-array

I'm trying to make a bar chart for a mobile devices that submit data.  Every minute, each mobile device sends a packet of data to the web server - where it's then stored in a MySQL database.  Each mobile device is assigned an IP addresses, and each IP address can send data multiple times a minute (sometimes as many as 10).  Here is what an example table would look like:

```
date_received | bytes | IP address
----------------------------------
1314831600    | 100   | 1482747555
1314831600    | 990   | 1482747555
1314831600    | 074   | 1482747555
1314831660    | 420   | 1482747555
1314831660    | 183   | 1482747555
```

So you can see that one IP address can submit multiple times a minute over a span of hours (therefore multiple minutes).  How would I create an associative array that looked like this:

```
array
(
   1314831600 = array
                (
                   1482747555 => 100,
                   1482747555 => 990,
                   1482747555 => 074
                );
   1314831660 = array
                (
                   1482747555 => 420,
                   1482747555 => 183
                );
);
```

The first key would be the date_received value, and the the IP addresses which are sent for that time (with their corresponding bytes values).  I'm using CodeIgniter and I thought about populating arrays in my foreach database loop, but wasn't quite sure how best to do this.  Does anybody have any advice?

**N.B:** I need to keep database calls to a minimum because some tables contain hundreds of thousands of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot share array keys like that (ip address) as they will be overwritten. You can do something like:

```
$packets = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $packets[$row['date_received']][] = 
        array('ip_address'=>$row['ip_address'], 
        'bytes'=>$row['bytes']
    );
}
```

Then you can loop through the data with:

```
foreach ($packets as $date => $info) {
    echo "date = $date, ip = $info[ip_address], bytes = $info[bytes]";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite part of your array like this, the problem becomes much easier for you:

```
        array
            (
               1482747555 => array(100,990,074)
            );
```